# Not getting news feed from facebook any more

Tags: iphone, facebook-graph-api, feed

I am using the following code to get the news feed from facebook-

```
NSString *urlStringFacebook = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/me/home?format=json&&access_token=%@&&limit=90",[[FBSession activeSession] accessTokenData]];

 NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[urlStringFacebook stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
    NSHTTPURLResponse *response;
    NSError *error;

NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
```

I have tried with different limit and different FB version.
Sometimes I get 3-4 feeds sometimes zero. It is happening only from 2 days before that I was getting news feeds.
Please help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is a facebook bug. I reported here-

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/449167695235902

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a bug.

File a report at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs